# How can I define this pattern using a regexp?

Tags: regex

I've got some *bad URL routes* that are hitting my website.

As such, I'm trying to filter out the bad routes by using a *Url Redirector* which requires *Regular Expressions* to match and replace.

---

I'm trying to find all..

`(s(2343243243....snip...1234723432))/aaa/bbbb`

and replace it with ...

`aaa/bbbb`

now these are the rules, though...

the text is `(` followed by a single `A-Z a-z 0-9` followed by another `(` followed by lots of random characters (it's a GUID) followed by two closing `))` then a slash, then my routes....

so ..

`(a(231231....snip....34334))/xxx` should be `xxxx`

and

`(F(34324 ... snip ... 1231))/foo/bah/pewpew` should be `foo/bah/pewpew`

#### Update

I'm also testing my regex matches [at this website](http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/regular_expressions.html). So these would be my inputs.

- `(s(2343243243....snip...1234723432))/aaa/bbbb`
- `(a(231231....snip....34334))/xxx`
- `(F(34324 ... snip ... 1231))/foo/bah/pewpew`

So I need to write the regular expression to get a match on that text.

Comment: @ruakh i've tried nothing because i'm still trying to learn how to do regex. Secondly, this is in .. no laguage? i'm just saying .. i have those pieces of text .. and wish to replace that text-block

Comment: This is not a real question. There is no such thing as ‘regex’. This cannot be answered in the vague.  Specify the ***exact*** language, library, program, tool — or close the question as not a real question.

Comment: @tchrist i've updated my question with more information. Does this give you some better context to my problem?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Kinda. It at least tells us where you expect to run it: on someone else’s website. I don’t understand why people don’t just run their tests on their own system with their own tools. With things like `sed` or `perl`, it is  trivial, and even Java patterns can be tested from the command line. I cannot understand why you would use some other language/tool for testing than you the actual one that you will use for deployment: **that seems a recipe for disaster** to me. Do you just not to know how to do basic command-line tests of these things?

Comment: @tchrist yeah, I do. I'm on windows so AFAIK, there's no sed or perl installed on this. nor java. so i'm using online tools (@Marty's link is excellent, actually. I'll be using that from now on). Secondly, i'm testing this on my own box -> it's in IIS to do my URL Rewriting, but i'm after some regex pattern which i can test against some inputs. I can never get my head around regex syntax :blush:

Comment: @Pure.Krome Test your regex better here http://regexr.com?300t2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^\([\w]\(.*\)\)/(.*)$` and replace it with the 1st group found `$1`, `l1`, `%1` or whichever language you're using, as `(` and `)` characters define a group (don't confuse with `\(` or `\)`).

`^` stands for *beginning of line*, `\w` stands for characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, `$` stands for *end of line*.

Here is the [regexpal.com example](http://regexpal.com/?flags=m&regex=%5C%28%5B%5Cw%5D%5C%28.%2a%5C%29%5C%29%2F%28.%2a%29&input=%28s%282343243243....snip...1234723432%29%29%2Faaa%2Fbbbb%0D%0A%28a%28231231....snip....34334%29%29%2Fxxx%0D%0A%28F%2834324%20...%20snip%20...%201231%29%29%2Ffoo%2Fbah%2Fpewpew) matching the Strings you posted.

And here is a [gskinner.com working example](http://regexr.com?300t2) with group replacements.

Comment: it has to match `))` at the end of the expression.

Comment: cheers! And LOVE the gskinner link .. how it actually explains to me what the parts of the regex are!!!! this is the money-shot :) So i can now learn this stuff :)

Comment: Glad it helped! http://www.regexbuddy.com used to have the same behavior, but I can't find it know, I think they're just selling its software :S

Comment: Why not simply replace `^\([\w]\(.*\)\)/` with the empty string? Also, this will not work if the part after the slash contains the substring `))/`.

Comment: @NiklasB. because he's asking for a regex..., he may need a couple more groups, say for friendly urls, and replacing just won't work there. (Just as he said: `As such, i'm trying to filter out the bad routes by using a Url Redirector which requires Regular Expressions to match and replace.` ) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try: `\([A-Za-z0-9]\((.+?)\)\/(.*)`

Comment: what would be the replacement, if i found a match. For example: i'm testing my inputs with this website: http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/regular_expressions.html

Comment: You'd replace the second matched group with a substring of itself minus the first character. That'd be easy enough. I'm not sure which language you are using though so I can't offer advice on the execution of that code.

Comment: If i have a single `)` at the end of the text (to be removed), it still matches (which is incorrect)